# PHP Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use

Tags: php, sockets, network-programming, port, centos6

Here is a simple server program:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
{
$host = "xxxxx";
$port=10000;
set_time_limit(0);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n".socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) );
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n".socket_last_error() );
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
$input = socket_read($spawn, 2048) or die("Could not read incoming connection\n");
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : ".$input."\n";
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
flush(); @ob_flush();
sleep(10);
}
?>
```

I am need to bind that port no. again after closing socket.
Every time, In the first loop there is no error, In the second loop iam getting error. I thought, the port wasn't cleared. I am using Cent OS, I tried some linux commands to refresh the ports,but no use.
 Can Anybody explain what actually happening in this case?
How can re use the same ports after closing in the same process?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create, bind, listen, and close the listening socket every time around the loop. So don't.

Comment: I know that.I can straightly read from and write to a client. Its just an example.But I need to do all those things, if first connection to a client fails to re-establish connection.